# pre, code, span - как правильно стилизовать и разметить?

Tags: html, css

Вставляю код в структуру

```
<pre><code><span>some css</span></code></pre>
```

Все работает как и описано в документации, но когда сами теги табулированы в файле и начинаются с 21 колонки, при отображении они также уезжают очень далеко, добавил `white-space: pre-wrap;` все стало на свои места, но когда в вставляемом коде идет больше одной строки и они должны быть табулированы по структуру, то все табы теряются и строки отображаются с одной линии.

Как правильно стилизовать эту структуру, чтобы

- код не уезжал на страничке
- по возможности сохранилась табуляция в html файле
- при многострочности табы код отображался как и задано в структуре

http://jsfiddle.net/falkone/npnccung/

При этом добавляется куча пустого пространства, понимаю что это из-за самой структуры в html, но ведь не вырезать код в первую колонку...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, если убрать лишние отступы и пробелы, именно они и придают ненужный отсуп слева....[так?](http://jsfiddle.net/npnccung/1/)

Избавится от нарушения структуры табуляции... да никак наверно, этот участок разметки чувстителен к пробелам

Comment: Надеялся что есть какой то "магический способ", но наверное так и сделаю.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поменять местами `<pre>` с `<code>`. И не стоит все это лепить друг в друга почти одно и тоже.

Я бы посоветовал бы вообще **отказаться от `<code>`** и взять , а еще лучше - **white-space:** pre или pre-wrap.